# Jquery .load Same origin policy

Tags: jquery, same-origin-policy

Is there anyway i can fool the Jquery .load Same origin policy? The closest i've come is with [this tutorial](http://www.badlydrawntoy.com/2008/07/08/yahoo-pipes-and-jquery-same-origin-policy/).

But that only deals with rss feeds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The same origin policy is a browser thing, not a jQuery thing.

[JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) is the usual way to work around this and is not limited to RSS feeds. It is even documented in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) (see the example that uses Flickr)

Comment: Cool, it seems to fit the bill, i'll attempt to grab html from an external page and get back to you!