# Why can't this jQuery redirect to another domain?

Tags: jquery

```
http://phplist.xxmn.com/zen/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=231
```

the js code,in dress.js:

```
$('#1d, #1a').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $('#producListing').load(this.attr('href'));
});
```

the big font Price UP and price down is the text i will click, i want to make when click the text the page can't refresh. thank you,

Comment: [Same origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453981/jquery-load-same-origin-policy)

Comment: is there a way to make it work?

Comment: No. Read Quentin answer in the linked question..

Comment: use yahoo pipes and jsonp to overcome Same origin policy issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the additional notes on the [jquery load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

If it is your domain, change the href to `/zen/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=231`
.

Comment: i change the url to /zen/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=231 , it still doesn't work. why?

Comment: Change `$('#producListing').load(this.attr('href'));` to `$('#productListing').load($(this).attr('href'));`.

Comment: Try following to update only the `div` with the id `productListing`: `$('#productListing').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #productListing');`

Comment: Clicking [your url](http://phplist.xxmn.com/zen/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=231&page=1&sort=3a) it works, have you cleaned your cache?

Comment: nope, i want to click the text Price Up or Price Down when on http://phplist.xxmn.com/zen/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=231
 this page, it works, not the URL,

Comment: If I click on `Price Down` the browser loads the complete page, searches the div `productListing` and replaces the the old with the new content. (Now you have changed something so it doesn't work.)

Comment: i haven't changed anything except delete this line event.preventDefault();

Comment: (You have removed the space before the #productListing.) If you only want to load a part of the html, you need another page, which outputs only this content.

Comment: scessor, now i want to add another function to it,When the user clicks Price Up, the Price Down  showing and Price Up should be hidden and vice versa. how do i do?

Comment: Sorry, have to go. Please make a new question, other people will help you. (If you think I could help you with your last question, it would be nice, if you could mark it as the right answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$('#1d, #1a').click(function(event){
    var myHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#producListing').load(myHref);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `this` in the jQuery-izer, `$(this)`.

Note also that there's no `#producListing`, it's `#productListing`.

And it loads a complete copy of the site into the div, which probably isn't what you want--but I assume you're testing.

Comment: SAD! i only want to load the productListing div. why it load all the page? is there a way to get only load the productListing div. thank you

Comment: @dreamchaser You're loading the contents of the URL you provided *into* that div. If you don't need the whole contents, then you should have a URL that returns only the HTML you actually need.

Comment: i know the reason why it loaded all the contents into the div, but i don't how to do that only load the productListing div. thank you

Comment: @dreamchaser What I'm saying is that it'll load whatever you tell it to load: if you're only trying to load a portion of HTML, then the HTML you return from the server should include *only* that HTML.

Comment: got it. but when i used load($(this).attr('href') + ' #productListing') it still doesn't work. it doesn't load the content successfully

Comment: @dreamchaser That doesn't load a portion of the HTML--put it in the URL bar and see what happens. **You need to return only the HTML you want to load.** Or, I suppose, parse it out, but it'd be *much* cleaner to return only what you want.

Comment: i am sorry, i don't know how to do. i only want to  when on phplist.xxmn.com/zen/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=231 this page,the user click the text Price Up or Price Down, the price can reordered but the page doesn't have a refresh

Comment: @dreamchaser Have a page on the server side that returns only the HTML in the product listing portion.

Answer (score 0):

scessor,

I see you've already fixed the 't' productListing.

Try this,

```
$('#1a,#1d').click(function(){
    $('#productListing').load(this);
    return false;
});
```

Better yet is to put a breakpoint in FireBug whenever you are unsure of the context that is available to you.