# Find attr('href') and open inside hidden iframe on the page, then show() iframe (jQuery + PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, function, dynamic

Language: **PHP and jQuery**

What I'm trying to do is pop up a dynamic link when a user clicks on it.
I don't want the page to be opened in a new window though, but in a modal one which overlays on the current page.

So with javascript, when a user clicks on this link, the action is to find the link's attr `href` and make a code for THAT link to be inside an iframe within the modal window.

The **HTML** with dynamic PHP link:

```html
 <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php echo $root_url; ?>?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>&title=<?php echo urlencode($rows['keyword']); ?>" style="border: none;" onclick="return false;" class="fblink" target="iframe"><img src="./img/Facebook.png" style="float: right; margin-top: 0px;" title="Share on Facebook" alt="Share on Facebook" id="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"></a>
```

The **jQuery script**:

```js
    var makePop = function() {
    link = $(this).attr('href');
    return '<div class="the_box" id="box" style="display: block;"><a class="boxclose" id="boxclose"></a>
    <iframe src="' + link + '" height="500px" width="600px" id="" name="iframe"></iframe></div>';
    } // End of Function.

    $("a.fblink").click(makePop);
```

I don't know how to make this happen... This is not working.
Anybody? **:o)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should provide what your looking for. However would need to consider issues such as same origin policy for the XHR 'load' call.

See example at: http://jsfiddle.net/qeXea/2/
**Note:** Due to same origin policy the iframe isn't able to populate with the content, simply setup your own page on your website and use your own urls to view.

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.yoururl.com" onclick="launchUrl(this); return false;">Click Here</a>
<div id="fade"></div>
<iframe id="dialog" src=""></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
function launchUrl(owner) {
    $('#fade').show();
    var link = $(owner).attr('href');
    $('#dialog').load(link, function(response) {
        $('#dialog').show();
    });
}
</script>
```

CSS

```
#fade {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

#dialog {
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 101;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

---

Alternative

HTML

```
<a href="" onclick="launchUrl('http://www.yoururl.com'); return false;">Click Here</a>
<div id="fade"></div>
<iframe id="dialog" src=""></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function launchUrl(link) {
        $('#fade').show();
        $('#dialog').load(link, function(response) {
            $('#dialog').show();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @JonWarnerNet, but I couldn't get this to work. When clicked, it just goes to the linked page like a normal link. I've previously noticed that when I use `onclick="function here ` stuff don't happen, so I'd have to catch a click from the script `$("a.link").click(function() {`

Comment: I've noticed that the onclick doesn't fire when it cannot find the function (as obviously it cannot call the js function if it cannot be found). If you have Firebug running in Firefox you'll notice a console log informing that the function does not exist. The fix (I believe) is to move the script block to the bottom of the page (before the </body> tag).

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work. When clicked, nothing happens. I've also tried putting the script above the other scripts. I am new to Firebug, so I don't know how to read errors, but under console **errors**, **warnings** and **debug info** they're all blank, except for the "**All**" tab. I see "onclick" & "anonymous" here.

Comment: Oh wait, it does work! But because I was at the bottom of the page and you had it absolute-positioned at the top, it wasn't in my line of view :) I have now changed it to fixed position. **Problem is...** nothing is loading inside the iframe... On Firebug when I click on the element, it shows this `<iframe id="dialog" src="" style="display: inline;">`

Comment: ensure you're script is calling from the same domain, see 'same origin policy' problems: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2453991/1441046

Comment: Could you please mark this as the answer if it answered your original question?

Answer (score 2):

There's no point returning a string from an event handler function, it won't do anything.

You need to actually create the modal window. Try [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for this.